# Octal arithmetic. If the octal is signed, what do I do?

Tags: computer-science, octal

> What is 4365 - 3412 when these values represent signed 12-bit octal numbers stored in sign-magnitude format? The result should be written in octal. Show your work.

So 4365 in binary is: 100 011 110 101
and 3412 in binary is: 011 100 001 010

Where do I go from here? Since it's sign magnitude, do I invert the bits in 4365 to: 011 100 001 010 and then subtract from there?

Comment: No, you don't invert any bits. But the leading `4` tells you that the sign bit is set, so `4365` actually represents `-425` (dec).

Comment: how do I know a sign bit is set? what is the rule for octal numbers?

Comment: Well, the sign bit is *usually* the most significant bit in sign-magnitude form. It should be properly documented though somewhere - in the task, in your lecture notes, etc.

Comment: @Bergi, Wouldn't a 12-bit signed octal given as `4365` represent `(-1803)` in decimal?  Not sure where that `(-425)` came from.

Comment: @Wyck The `4000` (0x800) bit is the sign, the other bits `0365` (0x0F5) are the magnitude.

Comment: @Bergi, then wouldn't that be `-245` in decimal?  I still don't see where `-425` is coming from.  Unless it's a typo of `-245`.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  So `4365` is a way of encoding `-365`.  And  `-365 - 3412 = -3777`.  And we encode `-3777` as `7777` (set the high bit).  Am I understanding _12-bit sign-magnitude_ now?

Comment: @Wyck yeah I'm also getting -245. How do you get 365?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks for the value of `4365 - 3412` represented in sign-magnitude format.  So:

1. Convert octal `4365` to decimal.  (It is negative!)
2. Convert octal `3412` to decimal
3. Compute the difference
4. Convert the answer to 12 bit signed magnitude (binary)
5. Translate into octal.

---

That's one way to do it.  Another way would be to calculate the difference in octal ... or binary ... arithmetic.  (How good are you are doing octal / binary arithmetic skills?)

Comment: How do you know 4365 is negative?

Comment: See @Bergi's comment.

Comment: I wouldn't convert to decimal, at least not in this example - much more complicated to calculate! You just need to strip off the sign bit, remember that you are adding two negative numbers, and then append the appropriate sign bit again.

Comment: I have suggested a number of ways to do it.  My first suggestion is the one that *I thought* would give the OP the greatest confidence that he has gotten the correct answer.  Also, what you say is not entirely correct.  You *also* need to do the arithmetic in octal ... which is not a skill that the OP may have learned.

Comment: Yeah, right - but when looking hard at the octal or the binary representation, one notices that not much *arithmetic* is actually necessary here :-)

Comment: Hmmm ... true.  But again, it all depends whether the aim of the problem that the OP is trying to solve is *primarily* about understanding representations or the skill of doing binary / octal arithmetic (by hand).

Answer (score 0):

4 octal digits represent 12 binary digits.

Presumably the sign-magnitude means that there is 1 bit to represent the sign and 11 bits of magnitude.  The sign bit is 0 if the magnitude is positive, and the sign bit is 1 if the magnitude is negative.

Interpretation of the 12-bit sign-magnitude format compared to an unsigned 12-bit number is as follows:

```
      [  Sign ][ Magnitude ]
      [-------][-----------]
BITS  [    11 ][      0-10 ]
```

Your question begins with ***reinterpreting*** the bits of the sign-magnitude encoded value as the bits of an unsigned 12-bit octal number given as `4365`.

We can decode this by looking at the binary bits.  (Really, just the most significant bit.)  We see that the sign is 1 (it's negative) and the remaining bits are the magnitude.

```
      ENCODED OCT   4365
      ENCODED BIN  [100 011 110 101]
         SIGN BIN  [1
    MAGNITUDE BIN    00 011 110 101]
             SIGN  negative (-)
    MAGNITUDE OCT   365
```

In practice, sign and magnitude can be easily read from the original octal representation by looking at the first digit.

- If the leading number is {0, 1, 2, 3} then it's positive.
- If the leading number is {4, 5, 6, 7} the magnitude is negative.  We remap the first digit of the number to {0, 1, 2, 3} respectively and then treat the result as the magnitude.  (or simply subtract 4 from the first digit)

Some examples:

- `4365` encodes `-0365`, or simply `-365`.
- `5234` encodes `-1234`.
- `3210` encodes `+3210`.
- `0000` encodes `+0000`, or simply `0`.
- `4000` encodes a "negative zero", which doesn't adversely affect arithmetic, but should be treated canonically as the quantity zero `0`.

To perform addition on two signed-magnitude numbers, just keep track of their sign bits.

- If the sign bits are the same, then just add the magnitudes and keep the sign bit.
- If the sign bits differ, subtract the smaller magnitude from the larger, and keep the sign of the larger.

To perform subtraction on two signed-magnitude numbers, just flip the sign of the second and then use the procedure for addition.

---

In your example, we note that we have a negative minus a positive, which means we will simply add the magnitudes and get a negative quantity.

The magnitudes are added in a straightforward digit-by-digit way like this:

```
    3 6 5
+ 3 4 1 2
---------
  3 7 7 7
```

And the sign of the result, according to the rule, will be negative.  So we need to do the reverse mapping on the first digit to set the 11th bit (the sign bit). {0, 1, 2, 3} maps to {4, 5, 6, 7} (or simply add 4 to the first digit).  So the 3 becomes a 7 and the final encoded number in octal is: **`7777`**

Comment: if I wanted to convert to binary first and then add... is there a way to do that?

Comment: oh I see 365 in octal = 245 in decimal

Comment: To convert from sign-magnitude to two's complement: Set the most significant bit (the sign bit) to zero, then invert all the bits, then add one.